Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info' from assembly Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
I am trying to migrate the .Net Core WebApi project from the version 2.1 to 8.0. But getting error -

TypeLoadException: Could not load type
'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info' from assembly
'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=7.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593'.

Please help me to solve this issue
I already installed the packages -

Swashbuckle,Swashbuckle.AspNetCore,
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger,
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen,
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI


Please add .csproj you have. Ideally a full [mre]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.




FolderProfile
true


Could you pls add <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" /> into your .csproj ->  section?

Just like you know, if you create a new .net 8 web api project, we will have Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package.

And in Program.cs or Startup.cs, the code snippet related to swagger is `builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
}`

You can create an empty Api application and then check Enable OpenApi. This will generate an Api application with Swagger. You can use this as a reference to see if the configuration is missing or otherwise caused

I installed Microsoft.OpenAi. But the same error occurs.
